# Area Enclosed By Tangents and Major Arc

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A chord AB of a circle of radius $5a$ is of length $3a$. The tangents to the circle at A and B meet at T. Find the area enclosed by TA, TB and the major arc AB.

I keep getting an answer of $81.20a^2$ but the book says $78.79a^2$, it would be great if someone can verify this is actually the correct answer as I don't see anything wrong in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't a particularly elegant one, but it certainly seems that the book's answer is closer.  I get

$$
25a^2 \Bigl( \pi + \frac{3}{\sqrt{91}} - \arctan \frac{3}{\sqrt{91}} \Bigr) \doteq 78.78457a^2
$$

which is rather closer to $78.79a^2$.  Based on your answer of $81.20a^2$, I suspect you have let the chord equal twice $3a$ (that is, $6a$), because then the answer would be

$$
25a^2 \Bigl( \pi + \frac{3}{4} - \arctan \frac{3}{4} \Bigr) \doteq 81.20222a^2
$$

Since the numbers work out nicely, it's entirely possible that the book's authors originally intended this problem, but made an error and rather than fix the problem statement (which might have already been set), simply gave the uglier answer.

Comment: You are spot on with the mistake I made. I will presume it's just a typo by the author as we have the same value (I have rechecked mine). Thanks for the help and I agree that the problem isn't an elegant one :)